# Python error: global name Xis not defined

Tags: python, compiler-errors, global-variables, undefined, helper

I've attached my Python Code below for a program our teacher as gave us in school. I keep on encountering an error "global name 'passwordValid' is not defined" and cannot find any way to solve this. This error occurs in the `Password.append(passwordValid)` line.

```
global firstName
global lastName
global cateGory
global passwordValid
global passwordNew
firstName = ""
lastName = ""
cateGory = ""


def newMember():
#Recieve user input to assign values to variables
    firstName = str(input("Please enter your first name."))
    lastName = str(input("Please enter your last name."))

    #Validation to reject unspecifyed category input
    cateGoryValid = False
    while cateGoryValid == False:
        cateGory = str(input("PLease enter your category from the following:    (Junior,Adult,Senior)"))
        cateGory = cateGory.lower()
        cateGory = cateGory.capitalize()
        if cateGory == "Junior" or cateGory == "Adult" or cateGory == "Senior":
            cateGoryValid = True
        else:
            cateGory = str(input("PLease enter your category from the following: (Junior,Adult,Senior)"))

def passwordValidation():
    #initalising global variables
    #Creating Variables
    Valid = False
    firstCharacter =""
    firstValue = 0
    lastCharacter =""
    lastValue = 0
    passwordNew = ""
    passwordValid = []

    #Create conditional loop to validate the password
    while Valid == False:
        passwordNew = str(input("Please enter a new password"))
        #Assigns both the first and last values of the password as variables
        firstCharacter = passwordNew[0]
        lastCharacter = passwordNew[-1]
        #Assigns both values as ASCII characters
        firstValue = ord(firstCharacter)
        lastValue = ord(lastCharacter)
        #Ensures password is within boundaries using ASCII characters
        if firstValue >= 65 and firstValue and lastValue >= 35 and lastValue <=37:
            passwordValid = passwordNew
            Valid = True

    return passwordValid

def valuesAppend():
    return passwordValid
    global Forname
    global Surname
    global Category
    global Password

    Forename = [""]
    Surname = [""]
    Category  =[""]
    Password = [""]
    Position = 0
    Members = ["","","",""] * 11

    #Reading the text file
    file = open("members.txt","rt")

    #Create loop to assign all fields to a record
    for line in file:
    fields = line.split(",")
    Members[Position] = [fields[0],fields[1],fields[2],fields[3]]
    #Appending the fields into a global variable
    Forename.append(fields[0])
    Surname.append(fields[1])
    Category.append(fields[2])

    Position = Position + 1

#Assigning new variables into the record
Forename.append(firstName)
Surname.append(lastName)
Category.append(cateGory)
Password.append(passwordValid)

file.close

def categoryInfo():
    totalMembers = 0
    totalMembers = len(Forename)

    for counter in range(len(Forename)):
        print(Forename[counter], Surname[counter],Category[counter])
        print("There are:",Category.count("Junior"),"Junior members.")
        print("There are:",Category.count("Adult"),"Adult members.")
        print("There are:",Category.count("Senior"),"Senior members.")
        print("The current total is:",totalMembers,"members.")

def main():
    newMember()
    passwordValidation
    valuesAppend()
    categoryInfo()

main()
```

Comment: change from this `passwordValidation` to this `passwordValidation()`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few bits wrong with the way your code is structured.

Firstly, you don't need to define your variables as globals, you only need to use 'global variable' within the local scope of a function so it knows it's accessing a global variable e.g.

```
password = "Password"
print(password) 
# prints "Password"

def update_pass():
    global password  # saying that the 'password' variable in this function refers to the global variable called 'password'
    password = "New password"

update_pass()
print(password)
# prints "New password"
```

Secondly, this block of code doesn't fall under any function and therefore would try to run before your main() function. Ensure this is correctly indented

```
#Assigning new variables into the record
Forename.append(firstName)
Surname.append(lastName)
Category.append(cateGory)
Password.append(passwordValid)
```

Lastly, this function is quite strange

```
def valuesAppend():
    return passwordValid
    global Forname
    # ...
```

Here, your valuesAppend() function will try to return passwordValid and that's it, once a return happens the rest of the code below isn't ran so you'll get no other use from your function

Hope this helps